# "Shared object "libicui18n.so.67" not found" error when running npm on freebsd

Tags: node.js, vue.js, unix, npm, freebsd

Basically i have installed node and i want to run vuejs project but for some reasons i cant use npm to install my project dependencies.

as i am using freebsd i use following command to install node.

```
  pkg add http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/All/npm-node10-6.12.1_1.txz
```

and now when i try to run npm : npm run dev

its showing me following errror:

```
Shared object "libicui18n.so.67" not found, required by "node".
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't forget to up-vote and accept an given answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is try to install "libicui18n.so.67" in freebsd so that node can find it.

If I understand correctly this is part of the [ICU 67 version](http://site.icu-project.org/download/67) part of the  [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: installed it by pkg add http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/All/cu-67.1,1.txz
still showing same error :(

Comment: Yes, this package is correct. I also checked it here https://freebsd.pkgs.org/11/freebsd-aarch64/icu-67.1,1.txz.html
Then it seems that the package exists, but node cannot find it.

Comment: while installing its tell the most recent version of icu-65.1,1 is already installed.
but still giving me same error Shared object "libicui18n.so.67" not found, required by "node". i tried alot to get this work :'(

Comment: Can you try to uninstall icu-65.1,1 and install again icu67.1,1?

Comment: no i cnt uninstall it as there are many dependency on it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you are running a supported version of FreeBSD. For 11 branch it is 11.4-RELEASE.

Try running `pkg update -f && pkg install -f node10 icu`. If this doesn't help, it means that it is a packaging problem and should be reported upstream: https://bugs.freebsd.org/

Also note that a more recent version of Node can be installed by `node` package. It doesn't depend on ICU at all.

Comment: my freebsd version is FreeBSD 11.3-STABLE amd64.
even after installing node version node-14.4.0.txz , still getting same error Shared object "libicui18n.so.67" not found, required by "node"

Comment: 11.3 is unsupported, and packages for it aren't getting updates anymore. Upgrade your FreeBSD system.

Comment: sorry for this i forgot to tell that im using pfsense 2.4.5-RELEASE with this version of freebsd, so if i try to upgrade freebsd my pfsense will not work.

Comment: the ouput of your command pkg update -f && pkg install -f node10 icu is 
 No packages available to install matching 'node10' have been found in the repositories